# Prev, Next and Done button on keyboard using xamarin for IOS Apps

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an IOS App developed using Xamarin Studio.

I have an UIView which has around 10 UITextView and UITextFields, I want the Keyboard to have Prev, Next and Done button which takes me to Previous and Next UIText fields.

I searched around and I got only Objective -C examples.

Can someone please help me to achieve this using Xamarin C# class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy:

the part above the kayboard is a simple UIView. So create your custom UIView with the three buttons:

```
UIView _topKeyboard = new UIView();

UIButton _prev = new UIButton(UIButton.Type.System);
_prev.SetTitle("Prev", UIControlState.Normal);
_prev.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0, 100,20);
_prev.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
 // Add the function of the key
};

UIButton _next = new UIButton(UIButton.Type.System);
// Set as above
UIButton _done = new UIButton(UIButton.Type.System);
// set as above

// now addit to the view

_topKeyboard.Add(_prev);

_topKeyboard.Add(_next);

_topKeyboard.Add(_done);
```

At the end you need to add this view to the UITextView or UITextFields that you want that it is shown with the method "InputAccessoryView":

```
_myTextView.InputAccessoryView = _topKeyboard
```

That's it! :)

Comment: Hey Thanks so much for the help. I am able to show this on my Keyboard. Any logic how can I move my cursor from one Texbox to other textbox in my UIView?